# Delphi - TDosCommand issue

Tags: batch-file, delphi

I need to call batch script from Delphi.
I'm using TDosCommand because I want to show echo messages from batch before external process finishes.
How to wait in procedure until script finishes?

Here is simple demo example. I'm calling Test.bat on click. Pause is only for testing purpose.

Test.bat.

```
@echo off

echo Script start
echo First line 
ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >nul 
echo Second line  
ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >nul 
echo Third line
ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul 
echo Fourth line
ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 4000 >nul
echo Script end
```

Pas file. Procedure ExecuteBatch calls batch script.
Added wait loop with Application.ProcessMessages. Is there any better solution then Application.ProcessMessages?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, DosCommand;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    btnExecuteBatch: TButton;
    procedure ExecuteBatch;
    procedure btnExecuteBatchClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DosCommand1NewLine(ASender: TObject; const ANewLine: string; AOutputType: TOutputType);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ExecuteBatch;
var
  i: integer;
  DosCommand1: TDosCommand;
begin
  DosCommand1 := TDosCommand.Create(Self);
  DosCommand1.OnNewLine := DosCommand1NewLine;
  DosCommand1.CommandLine := '..\..\Test.bat';
  DosCommand1.Execute;

  repeat
    sleep(100);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  until (DosCommand1.EndStatus <> esStill_Active);

  //here I need to wait until Test.bat script finishes
  // (repeat-until?)

  RichEdit1.Lines.Add('End of ExecuteBatch procedure.');

end;

procedure TForm1.DosCommand1NewLine(ASender: TObject; const ANewLine: string; AOutputType: TOutputType);
begin
  if AOutputType = otEntireLine then
  begin
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add(ANewLine);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnExecuteBatchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Clear;
  ExecuteBatch;
end;

end.
```

Dfm file of test form. I'm using RichEdit because I will need to change color of some lines.

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 645
  ClientWidth = 924
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object RichEdit1: TRichEdit
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 633
    Height = 629
    Font.Charset = EASTEUROPE_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -11
    Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Font.Style = []
    Lines.Strings = (
      'RichEdit1')
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 0
    Zoom = 100
  end
  object btnExecuteBatch: TButton
    Left = 696
    Top = 16
    Width = 113
    Height = 41
    Caption = 'Execute Batch'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = btnExecuteBatchClick
  end
end
```

Comment: Why don't you use ICS or Indy or other Delphi library for TCP/IP? They have a ping component ? And if not a TCP/IP library, why use DosCommand instead of ShellExecute or CreateProcess to run the command interpreter passing the batch file?

Comment: Sorry, ignore what is in batch script. It is not related with ping. In real script is call of gcc compiler. I'm using this control because it can write external process messages to RichEdit (DosCommand1NewLine) and because of Stop and SendLine methods.

Comment: You should better use real thing in your question. Anyway, you can run anything using ShellExecute or CreateProcess, include gcc. That's what TDosCommand do anyway. TDosCommand use a thread to let the process run in the background, just what you don't want...

Comment: Looking at TDosCommand source code, you have 3 ways to know if the started process is running: use property ExitCode or property EndStatus or event OnTerminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [TDosCommand source code](https://github.com/TurboPack/DOSCommand/blob/master/Source/DosCommand.pas), you have 3 ways to know if the started process is running: use property `ExitCode`, or property `EndStatus`, or event `OnTerminated`.

Using `OnTerminated` event would avoid building a wait loop, which is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Added wait loop. Is there any better solution then Application.ProcessMessages?

Comment: I want to show echo messages from batch file before external process is terminated. So this is not an option. Is there any way then using DosCommand control?

Comment: @Ivan the answer told you what to do - DO use the `OnTerminate` event. DONT use a busy wait loop at all. Break up your code into two steps. Start the batch file running, **then exit**, letting flow return to the main message loop. Later, the event will be called, so you can continue your code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code as close to what it was, you could check IsRunning property.

```
while DosCommand1.IsRunning do
begin
    sleep(100);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```